# Zend_Config_Xml

Tags: zend-framework, zend-config-xml

So i will list my problems here, please help

First of all, i use Zend_Http_Client to call to an url:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://mydomain.com/Statistics.aspx?activity=top');
$response = $client->request('POST');
$response = $response->getRawBody();
```

Then i get an Xml document structure for $response when i print it out:

```
[?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?]

[root]
    [member]
        [username>gh_MXH[/username]
        [money]129300[/money]
    [/member]
    [member]
        [username]sonhothiet_MXH[/username]
        [money]107400[/money]
    [/member]
[/root]
```

After that, i use Zend_Config_Xml:

```
$xmlReader = new Zend_Config_Xml($response);
$xml = $xmlReader->toArray();
```

But all i get is just only the first element of the array when i print out $xml:

```
Array
(
    [member] => Array
        (
            [username] => gh_MXH
            [money] => 129300
        )

)
```

Please show me how to get all the elements so that i can do the looping like:

```
foreach($xml as $key => $value){
    echo $value['username'] . 'has' . $value['money'];
}
```

And one more question, when i wrote:

```
$xml = new Zend_Config_Xml($response, 'root');
```

It appears an error saying: Section 'root' cannot be found in. Really need your help. Thank you and sorry for bad English.

Comment: Are you sure that you get "[" instead of "<" for the nodes??

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Zend_Config_Xml` to parse standard XML docments, it is for config files. PHP can easily do this natively:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
foreach($xml->member as $member){
    echo $member->username . 'has' . $member->money;
}
```